# Как добавить новую строчку в csv, при этом сохранив старую

Tags: c#, файлы, csv, файловый-ввод-вывод

```
string a = "AAA";
string b = "BBB";
string c = "CCC";

string pathCsvFile = "F:\\csv.csv";

if (!File.Exists(pathCsvFile))
{
    File.Create(pathCsvFile);
}

var csv = new StringBuilder();

var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", a, b, c);
csv.AppendLine(newLine);

File.WriteAllText(pathCsvFile, csv.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("Готово!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но в таком случае первая строчка переписывается. Считывать файл и перезаписывать не хочется, так как это странно как-то.

Comment: `StringBuilder` вам здесь не нужен. Если вы хотите добавить стоку к файлу, используйте `AppendAllText`, а не `Write`, который перезапишет файл. Ну и создавать/проверять существование файла вам не нужно, эти методы сами создадут файл если нужно будет.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `WriteAllText` можно использовать [`AppendAllLines`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines):

```
File.AppendAllLines(pathCsvFile, new []{newLine});
```

В принципе, ни `StringBuilder`, ни проверка существования файла здесь не обязательны:

```
string a = "AAA";
string b = "BBB";
string c = "CCC";

string pathCsvFile = "F:\\csv.csv";

File.AppendAllLines(pathCsvFile, new []{$"{a},{b},{c}"});
Console.WriteLine("Готово!");
Console.ReadKey();
```